# Multiple uploads

Tags: file, ftp, uploading

Hi I need to upload the files to FTP from three different classes simultaneously.. How can i handle it using connection Kit .. If i use thread for three classes uploading will not be done. I think for uploading it is using the main thread of the application.. How can i separate this into three main threads so that uploading should be carried out Simultaneously... Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create three separate connections to the server if you want to upload files simultaneously via FTP (and your FTP server must allow you to open at least 3 connections). It wont work if you just create a wrapper class that will connect only once and thread it.

Comment: Thank you for replying me....
     I am using three different objects in three classes like
id <AbstractConnectionProtocol>conOne;
id <AbstractConnectionProtocol>conTwo;
id <AbstractConnectionProtocol>conThree;

It connects fine to the ftp simultaneously but while uploading one will wait for the other to complete. Is this because all the three are using the main thread?..